# PHP HTML select box selected from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

A simple code that inserts a list of teams in select box. 
I would like to set SELECTED team with a id , that is in HREF

```
http://localhost/teams.php?id=7&years=2011&cups=8   

<?php
    $query = "select distinct t.team_id,t.team from teams t,years y,cups c where t.team_id=c.team_id and y.year_id=$_GET[years] and c.cup_id=$_GET[cups] ORDER BY t.team ASC";
    $res   = mysql_query($query);
    $option = '';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['team_id'].'">'.$row['team'].'</option>';
    }
?>

<form>
    <select id="tteam" name="team">
        <?php echo $option; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

The problem is that I set team_id=$_GET[id], it shows only one team.
I want the team=7 to be selected, but others still be showing in select box

Comment: That's one problem, yes.  A bigger problem is that your code is ***wide open*** to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware that you're vulnerable to SQL injections. See: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

With that said, you need to use a conditional statement that compares `$row["team_id"]` with `$_GET["ID"]`.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
if($row["team_id"] == $_GET["ID"])
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['team_id'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['team'].'</option>';
else
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['team_id'].'">'.$row['team'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: I agree about SQL injections , I will looking into that!

Comment: There's an error in this code. In your `if` condition, you're using `$_GET[ID]`. If ID is an undefined constant, this will result in a PHP Notice.

Comment: $_GET["id"] is much faster than $_GET[id]

Comment: @kumar_v $_GET['id'] with single quotes, although insignificantly, rather than double quotes, however specifying ID without quotes is simply an error!

Answer (score 3):

1st of all, NEVER EVER insert raw data into an SQL query. You are asking for SQL injections.
Secondly, you're missing quotes around your $_GET variables, for example, in your SQL query, you currently access id by using `$_GET[id]`. This won't work, encapsulate `id` in quotes, like `$_GET['id']`.
Thirdly, ESCAPE your data!!

`mysql_*` functions are now deprecated. You shouldn't be using them in new code. Instead, look into PDO or MySQLi functionality. Also look into prepared queries.

This should be your code:

```
<?php
   $years = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['years']);
   $cups = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cups']);

    $query = "SELECT distinct t.team_id, vt.team 
              FROM teams t,years y,cups c 
              WHERE t.team_id = c.team_id 
                  AND y.year_id = '{$years}' 
                  AND c.cup_id = '{$cups}' 
              ORDER BY t.team ASC";

    $res   = mysql_query($query);
    $option = '';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        // The line below specifies whether the option should be selected.
        $selected = $row['team_id']==$_GET['id'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

        $option .= '<option ' . $selected . ' value= "' . $row['team_id'] . '">' . $row['team'] . '</option>';
    }
?>

<form>
    <select id="tteam" name="team">
        <?php echo $option; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is a better idea, but building SQL queries is not a great idea.

Comment: @josh I don't understand! Whats not great about building SQL queries?

Comment: These functions are *deprecated*. They may, in consequence, have lost some of their material value. Alternatively, their scarcity may serve to enhance their value; I just don't know. ;-)

Comment: Lol, I still have problems pronouncing it for some reason!

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['team_id'].'" '.($row['team'] == 7 ? 'selected="selected"': '').'>'.$row['team'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: You probably want to remove the `echo` there.

Comment: @scenia Ta, missed that :)

Comment: +1 for ternary operator btw, that's what I would have posted if I had understood the question in the first place :D

Answer (score 0):

Compare your id from $_GET with $row['team_id'].

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
if($row['team_id'] == $_GET["id"])
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['team_id'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['team'].'</option>';
else
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['team_id'].'">'.$row['team'].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just focus on the loop part:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $selected = (isset($_GET['team_id']) && $row['team_id'] == $_GET['team_id']) ? 'selected' : '';
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['team_id'].'" selected="'. $selected .'">'.$row['team'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: This won't work. It sets `selected=""` on all option except the one supposed to be selected, which will be `selected="7"` if he passes 7. The correct syntax would be `selected="selected"`.

Comment: Ah of course it does ! Overlooked that very important detail, thanks for pointing it out :)